# How to prove $BA=0 \implies $ nullity $B \geq $ rank $A.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am stuck on the following problem and do not know how to progress:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ real matrices. Then how can I prove that  $BA=0 \implies $ nullity $B \geq $ rank $A.$

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Read this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341357/let-a-and-b-be-n-times-n-real-matrices-such-that-ab-ba-0-and-ab-is-i

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: This says that $\text{im}(A)\subseteq\ker B$--what's true about vector space dimension and containment?

Comment: Sir,can you clarify a bit more about why " $\text{Im}(A)\subseteq\ker B$" and the given problem are equivalent.

Comment: @user53386 Everything that is in the iamge of $A$ is in the kernel of $B$ (why)? This says that the image of $A$ is contained in the kernel of $B$. But, the rank of $A$ is the dimension of its image, and the nullity of $B$ is the dimension of its kernel. Since this image of $A$ is contained in the kernel of $B$ this gives us the desired inequality (why?)

Answer (score 4):

$A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix.then it goes a vector space with $n$ dimension to an another vector space also about $B!$
but when $BA=0$ is means that every base from image of $A$ will be at kernel of $B$. so $B$ at least has all of basis of image $A$, so null $B$≥ rank $A$.

Comment: $\Huge{+1}~~~~$

Answer (score 3):

Another way of viewing this is that everything in the range of $A$ is sent to $0$ and is therefore in the Kernel of $B$. What does that say about the dimensions of these spaces?