# Sum of idempotent matrices is Identity

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, idempotents

> **[Ciarlet, Problem $1.1-10$]** Let $A_k$, $1 \leq k\leq m$, be matrices of order $n$ satisfaying
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^mA_k\ =\ I.$$
>   Show that the following conditions are equivalent.
>
> 1. $A_k = (A_k)^2$, $1  \leq k \leq m$,
> 2. $A_kA_l=0$, for $k\neq l$, $1\leq k,l\leq m$
> 3. $\sum\limits_{k=1}^m\mbox{rank}(A_k) = n$.

*Remark*: We already proved $(2)\to(1)$ and $(1)\to(3)$, but we couldn't prove $(3)\to(2)$ or $\{(3)\to(1)\;\; and\;\; (1)\to(2)\}$. Please help us, thanks so much.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341357/let-a-and-b-be-n-times-n-real-matrices-such-that-ab-ba-0-and-ab-is-i/341370#341370 - See this for the gist of the proof that (2) implies (3).  Not quite what you asked but maybe it will give details as to how to show the converse

Comment: It's difficult, because that gist it doesn't work in backwards :S

Answer (score 4):

Condition **3** implies that your vector space is a direct sum of the images of the operators, i.e.
$$V = \bigoplus_{k=1}^m\mathrm{Im}(A_k)$$
Without loss of generality, let us focus on $A_1$. If $\mathbf{x}\in \ker(A_1)$ then
$$\mathbf{x} = A_1\mathbf{x} + A_2\mathbf{x} + \cdots + A_m\mathbf{x} = A_2\mathbf{x} + \cdots + A_m\mathbf{x}$$
Therefore it follows that $\ker(A)\subseteq \mathrm{Im}(A_2)\oplus \cdots \oplus \mathrm{Im}(A_m)$. On the other hand, if $\mathbf{x} \in \mathrm{Im}(A_2)\oplus \cdots \oplus \mathrm{Im}(A_m)$ then
$$\mathbf{x} = A_2\mathbf{x_2} + \cdots + A_m\mathbf{x_m}$$
for some $\mathbf{x_i}\in V$. But we also have
$$\mathbf{x} = A_1\mathbf{x} + A_2\mathbf{x} + \cdots + A_m\mathbf{x}$$
By uniqueness of representation, we must have $A_1\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ so $\mathbf{x}\in\ker(A_1)$. This shows
$$\ker(A_1) = \bigoplus_{k=2}^m\mathrm{Im}(A_k)$$ 
And in particular, we have
$$V = \mathrm{Im}(A_1) \oplus \ker(A_1)$$
For $\mathbf{x}\in \mathrm{Im}(A_1)$ we also have 
$$\mathbf{x} = A_1\mathbf{x} + A_2\mathbf{x} + \cdots + A_m\mathbf{x}= A\mathbf{x}$$
since by uniqueness of representation, we get that $A_k\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ for $k>1$. The two properties above characterizes $A_1$ as a projection. That's **3** implies **1**.

The above argument also shows **2**, since if we have
$$\ker(A_1) = \bigoplus_{k=2}^m\mathrm{Im}(A_k)$$
then this trivially implies that for $k\neq 1$
$$A_k\mathbf{x} \in \mathrm{Im}(A_k) \subseteq \ker(A_1)$$
so that we get $A_1A_k\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ for all $\mathbf{x}\in V$ and all $k\neq 1$.

Finally as a note, **1** to **2** is probably most easily done through **1** to **3** to **2**. Condition **1** very easily implies condition **3** since for projections, the trace is equal to the rank. This means
$$n = \mathrm{tr}(I) = \sum_{k=1}^m\mathrm{tr}(A_k) = \sum_{k=1}^m\mathrm{rank}(A_k)$$

**Edit**: I apologize for leaving out a key condition above. Hopefully this will make more sense. Let $A$ be a linear operator on an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$. The *two* conditions

1. $\ker(A)\oplus\mathrm{Im}(A) = V$
2. $A^2\mathbf{x} = A\mathbf{x}$ for $\mathbf{x}\in\mathrm{Im}(A)$

together characterize $A$ as an idempotent operator. I use the term "projection" synonymously with "idempotent linear transformation". This is the standard definition to my knowledge. For example, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28linear_algebra%29) uses it.

To see this, note that for any $\mathbf{v}\in V$ we can write $\mathbf{v}$ uniquely as
$$\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y},\ \ \ \ \mathbf{x}\in\mathrm{Im}(A),\ \ \mathbf{y}\in\ker(A)$$
Then this of course means that
$$A^2\mathbf{v} = A^2(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}) = A^2\mathbf{x} = A\mathbf{x} = A(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}) = A\mathbf{v}$$
so that $A$ is indeed idempotent on $V$.

Comment: How does (3) imply a **direct** sum?

Comment: @SteveD If a sum of subspaces equals an $n$ dimensional vector space and the dimensions of those subspaces total $n$ then the vector space is a direct sum of the subspaces. To see this, fix a basis for each subspace. Then the union of the basis are $n$ vectors which span an $n$-dimensional vector space, meaning the union is itself a basis. In particular, this shows that the subspaces themselves are independent in the first place.

Comment: Where do you use the fact of $\sum A_k = I$?

Comment: @FASCH The second line. "If $\mathbf{x}\in \ker(A_1)$ then ...". Actually, the fact that $V$ is a direct sum of the images relies directly on the fact that the operators sum to the identity.

Comment: Could you please, explain to me, why "That's 3 implies 1."? Thanks

Comment: @FASCH I had already mentioned that $\ker(A_1) \oplus \mathrm{Im}(A_1)$ characterizes $A_1$ as a projection. Are you unsure why that condition implies that $A_1$ is a projection?

Comment: Yes, and also what is the projection definition that you used

Comment: @FASCH I see your confusion. I apologize for leaving out a key condition previously. Hopefully it's more clear now.